# Getting method is undefined for the type String error while resolving IP

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to convert IP to web address and vice versa in a tool which is created using Swing.
The action listener part is here

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==check1)
    {
        String ipresult,queryip=inputip.getText();

        try
        {
            InetAddress ip1=InetAddress.getByName(queryip);
            ipresult=queryip.getHostName();
            outputweb.setText(ipresult);        
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            outputweb.setText("Please check the IP address");
        }
    }

    if(e.getSource()==check2)
    {
        String webresult,queryweb=inputweb.getText();
        try
        {
            InetAddress web1=InetAddress.getByName(queryweb);
            webresult=queryweb.getHostAddress();
            outputip.setText(webresult);

        }
        catch(Exception e2)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am doing this on Eclipse, so the error it says at 
the line `webresult=queryweb.getHostAddress();` and `ipresult=queryip.getHostName();`
is `method is undefined for the type String`

What is that I am doing wrong? I can post in the full code if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 3):

Well this looks like the problem:

```
InetAddress ip1=InetAddress.getByName(queryip);
ipresult=queryip.getHostName();
```

I suspect you meant:

```
InetAddress ip1 = InetAddress.getByName(queryip);
ipresult = ip1.getHostName();
```

Basically you were calling `getHostName` on `queryip`, rather than on `ip1`. You then have the exact same mistake for the second piece of code - which looks sufficiently similar to the first piece that you should consider extracting a method which could be called in both cases.

However, you shouldn't *just* fix your code. You should take a step back and work out why you couldn't figure this out for yourself:

- Did you read the error message carefully?
- Did you look at the code carefully, to work out *why* the compiler was complaining about that line?
- Do you actually understand (from a language perspective) every line of your code?

It's not a problem to not know things - it's a problem if you don't learn from your mistakes.

Comment: well... it still is a problem not to know things that is why SE sites usually have the solution :D.  Good answer though, +1

Comment: Oh oops, thanks. I dint realized that I was calling queryip :< my bad.. Thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help in this case

```
String clientIp  =  request.getRemoteHost();
System.out.println(clientIp);
InetAddress Address =InetAddress.getByName(clientIp); 
System.out.println("Testing client name:"+Address.getHostName());
```

Answer (score 0):

`getHostAddress()` is not defined for the type String. It is a method of the class`InetAddress` but you are invoking it on `queryweb` which is a `String`

Answer (score 0):

queryip is of string type as per

```
 String ipresult,queryip=inputip.getText();
```

Your getting that error because string does not have a method getHostName(). Now if you were to have a object initialized that had such a method you could call it. Just guessing from your code you should make it:

```
 ipresult=ip1.getHostName();
```

You should have some object that has a string field and has a method getHostName(). You may want to consider a static class with a method getHostName(String ip). This all depends on how much you need an InetAddress object